# Sampling Groundwater for CFCs

Tags: environmental-chemistry

Possibly stupid question from a non chemist (field hydrologist). I am trying to sample groundwater for CFCs for the purpose of age dating water. I am planning on sampling with a peristaltic pump (such that the water doesn't come into contact with the atmosphere) using Viton tubing. However, the short length (~ 6") of tubing that fits into the pump itself is not Viton (it's silicon), as I couldn't find any Viton with a large enough wall thickness to work. My question is this: could the water running through that short length for that short an amount of time potentially contaminant the sample? Thanks and my apologies if this is not the right place for this question.

Comment: You did not mention detection technique. If you are detecting CFCs, don't use any sampling device that itself contains fluorinated compounds like Viton. Alternatively, you can do a control test, by soaking Viton tubing for more than 2-3 days in water and get it analyzed.